# How can I filter out from Function List?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ has a Function List feature that allows for quick jumping to functions. This is all fine and dandy, but I find that if I'm working in JavaScript and use anonymous functions, then it quickly becomes very silly; my current file has almost 100 instances of "function" in the list!

I know that it has a filter, but that only allows you to search for a specific function. Is there a way I can filter out anonymous functions (or any function names in general)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the regular expression that finds the functions (see [Notepad++ help](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html)).

Find the `js_function` parser and change the first *nameExpr* inside the *functionName* element from

`"[_A-Za-z][\w_]*[\s]*[=:]|[_A-Za-z]?[\w_]*[\s]*\("`

to

`"[_A-Za-z][\w_]*[\s]*[=:]|(?<=function )[_A-Za-z]?[\w_]*[\s]*\("`

This adds a lookbehind to the expression, ensuring that the word "function " (including a space) precedes the function name. If it doesn't, it's an anonymous function and will not show up in the function list.

Comment: Excellent! David Blanchard's answer worked like a charm. BTW - the file that David is referring to is functionList.XML and is found in: C:\Users\<USER NAME>\AppData\Roaming\notepad++

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even see this answer. Thanks, it works great!

Comment: Now, the suggested trick does not work anymore because npp does not support look behind operations (see the Notes on regular expressions for parsers in https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/function-list/#how-to-customize-function-list)